# Flask application not giving output after running Python35

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Here is the code of my application I am trying to run:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
import json
import requests
import socket
from datetime import datetime
import pickle
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/tables.html')
def tables():
    return render_template('tables.html')

@app.route('/flot.html')
def flot():
    return render_template('flot.html')

@app.route('/morris.html')
def morris():
    return render_template('morris.html')

@app.route('/forms.html')
def forms():
    return render_template('forms.html')

@app.route('/panels-wells.html')
def panelswells():
    return render_template('panels-wells.html')

@app.route('/buttons.html')
def buttons():
    return render_template('buttons.html')

@app.route('/notifications.html')
def notifications():
    return render_template('notifications.html')

@app.route('/typography.html')
def typography():
    return render_template('typography.html')

@app.route('/icons.html')
def icons():
    return render_template('icons.html')

@app.route('/blank.html')
def blank():
    return render_template('blank.html')


@app.route('/login.html')
def login():
    return render_template('login.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True, threaded=True)
    pass
```

Here is how I ran it:

```
C:\Users\aims\Desktop\forex>python forex_app.py
 * Serving Flask app "forex_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 122-288-656
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:8080/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Detected change in 'C:\\Users\\aims\\Desktop\\forex\\forex_app.py', reloading
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 122-288-656
```

After hitting the url as: `http://0.0.0.0:8080` or even `http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html` I see the following screen:
[image: output image]

Kindly, help me what I am missing. I have the `html` templates available in the `templates` folder. See the image:
[image: folder images]

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong here.

`0.0.0.0` is not an address you put into the browser; it's a special value to tell the server to bind to any address. You need to access the site via the localhost IP, which is `127.0.0.1:8080`.

Secondly, you don't define a route handler in your Flask code for the root path; you only define "index.html", and so on. I suspect that you are misunderstanding what is going on there; the route is what you put into the browser, and it is not in any way related to the template you render. It is quite possible (and preferable) to define a route for `/` but for the handler to render "index.html":

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Answer (score 1):

try 127.0.0.1:8080, the 0.0.0.0:8080 just means the app is listening for all connections